# kubectl get pods running on each node along with status of the node

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to get something like this

```
PodName | Status | Node Name | Status of Node
```

The status of the Node could be Ready or Not Ready ?

Comment: That seems like something reasonably straightforward to build using the Kubernetes API; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can get custom info with custom columns like so:

```
kubectl get pod <PODNAME> -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName -n <NAMESPACE>
```

I didn't see the node status value describing the pod.